# Why are visitors to my website seeing kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 310?

Tags: safari, next.js, mobile-safari, netlify, cfnetwork

I have an app with Next.js that is hosted on Netlify. It's a very high traffic app, and there are some routes which are frequently emdeded by users in an iframe. On the embedded pages, we're noticing a very high (~20-30%) rate of errors in Google Analytics, mostly for visitors in Safari (but not exclusively).

The error message the users see is "kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 310". I've searched for that, and I can't find any documentation about what the error means or hints what the cause might be. Does anyone know what "kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 310" is or have any idea what might cause >20% of our visitors to see this error?

Comment: Is the error happening on specific pages of the website? Have you tried replicating the issue locally on Safari?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error on older safari browsers 13.04 and lower. Did you figure it out? Also when requests are shown in the network tab, I can see it sets port "0", instead of default port and setting it manually does not help.